# Running a function when button clicked, not on released

Tags: python, button, tkinter

When we use tkinter, buttons calls the function after we clicked and released the button. How can we call the function when we clicked the button

Comment: please show ur code that you have attempted?

Answer (score 0):

Mouse clicks can be bound to a button by binding the `<Button-[1|2|3]>` event: `myButton.bind("<Button-1>", myfunc)`. Binding `<ButtonRelease-1>` would call the bound function when the button is released.